# Missing Material Icons when offline with nuxt js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

npm install nuxt-material-design-icons-iconfont -D

is this correct

Comment: Hi, what is the question? What do you mean by offline? For the end user, for you to work with?

Comment: @kissu it mean by without internet
actually i want to get displayed material icons without internet in my web application

Comment: I still do not understand tbh. You want to run your project locally with those icons while on a plane for example? Then, once your have installed your packages, you will have them locally in your `node_modules`, hence no need for an Internet connection. Or is it for your website's visitors? Because if they do not have Internet, they cannot really reach your website neither.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.